# Connect Crystal reports with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, crystal-reports

I am currently using Crystal Reports 2013.

I have following configuration in CRConfig.xml file

```
<JDBCURL>localhost:27017</JDBCURL>
<JDBCClassName>jdbc:mongodb</JDBCClassName>
```

I have also copied the  mongo-2.10.1.jar file in the lib directory under C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java\lib folder.

downloaded mongo-2.10.1.jar from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads

When I open Crystal Reports and open new crystal reports. I try to connect to JDBC(JNDI) through the available Datasources option, upon click of finish, I get following error.. Failed to open the connection. Details: JDBC driver not found.

Some help in configuration in CRConfig.xml would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it worked with UnityJDBC : http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php

### Settings in CRConfig.xml file are as follows.

```
<Classpath>C:\mongodb\jdbcdriver\mongo-java-driver-  2.11.2.jar;C:\mongodb\jdbcdriver\mongodb_unityjdbc.jar;

<JDBC>
            <CacheRowSetSize>100</CacheRowSetSize>
            <JDBCURL>jdbc:mongo://localhost:27017/claimLoadingDB</JDBCURL>
```

### mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a NoSQL database and therefore does not support JDBC connections, there's no JDBC driver for it.  You won't be able to connect a standard reporting tool like Crystal reports to MongoDB.

You have a few alternative options:

1. I've heard that [JasperSoft have tools](https://www.jaspersoft.com/instant-analytics-for-mongodb) for reporting against MongoDB
2. You can write a job that exports your MongoDB data into a traditional SQL database and connect Crystal to the SQL database
3. You can write your own tool to pull information out of MongoDB using one of the language drivers.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't plan to add support for JDBC, it's really not a good match for interacting with a Document database.

Comment: CRConfig.xml is a file provided by Crystal Reports where the jar class path settings .